# NullReferenceException when referencing an XML Element that doesn't exist

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am receiving the following error when trying to access an XML element that doesnt exist using linq:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
>   occurred in Test.exe System.NullReferenceException: Object reference
>   not set to an instance of an object.

```
bool exists = website.Parent
            .Element("Exclusions")
            .Elements("Exclusion")
            .Where(x => thisKeyword.ToUpper().Contains((string)x.Value.ToUpper() ?? "~"))
            .Any();
```

I can remedy the issue by simply using `.Where(x => thisKeyword.Contains((string)x))`

But I need to convert both `thisKeyword` and the XML element value (if it exists) to upper case to get a case-insensitive comparison.

I was under the impression that  `?? "~"` meant that "if whats the left is null use what is to the right. So in this case `x` should become tilde, and therefore not validate against `thisKeyword` (as it wont ever contain tilde). A crude method I agree...but it doesn't even work.

How can I protect against the NullReferenceException?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Look at what is null, thisKeyword, x, or  x.Value will kill you. Have to do a null check first.

Comment: I think that you can use the following code `thisKeyword?.ToUpper().Contains((string)x?.Value.ToUpper() ?? "~")` for checking that both aren't null

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `x.Value` is null and `thisKeyword` is known to be non-null:

The crash is happening because the `??` operator is trying to check whether the value returned by `ToUpper()` is null. However, it can't call `ToUpper()` because `x.Value` does not exist.

In C# version 6 or later you can use the *null propagation operator*, `?.`, which accesses a property if and only if the object is non-null:

```
.Where(x => thisKeyword.ToUpper().Contains(
            (string)x.Value?.ToUpper() ?? "~")
```

Alternatively, just use a separate `Where` clause to check that `x.Value` is non-null:

```
.Where(x => x.Value != null)
.Where(x => thisKeyword.ToUpper().Contains(x.Value.ToUpper())
```

As an aside, you could put the condition inside the `Any()` clause instead:

```
.Elements("Exclusion")
.Any(x => x.Value != null && thisKeyword.ToUpper().Contains(x.Value.ToUpper())
```

And you don't necessarily need to convert to upper case either:

```
.Any(x => x.Value != null &&
          thisKeyword.IndexOf(x.Value,
             StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > 0)
```

Comment: You are on the right track, but instead of messing around with the Elvis operator you can instead use something far simpler - the [string.Equals(string, string, comparisonType)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4411bks(v=vs.110).aspx) static method.It is tolerant of nulls, and you can specify a case insensitive check (which is the most common reason why people do a ToUpper() or ToLower() before checking).

Comment: Thanks for this. It looks like I cannot use the Value?. property so I must be on an older version of C#.

My next issue is how I should deal with NullReferenceException if .Elements("Exclusion") and .Element("Exclusions") do not exist in the XML?